# Magento skin_js path in page.xml

Tags: javascript, xml, magento, path

I tried to add a javascript with a custom template through its page.xml like this:

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>myjs.js#notify</name></action>
```

Notify will throw an alert windows so I can check if it's correct after reload. In addition I check the source code to see where it tries to go. Template is correctly setup and cache is flushed.

With the above script it goes to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1/magento/skin/frontend/base/default/myjs.js#notify"></script>
```

Which doesn't exist here.

Script is located in skin/frontend/default/blank2/js/live.js

Answer (score 15):

Try changing (assuming that myjs.js is in skin/frontend/default/blank2/js/myjs.js)

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>myjs.js#notify</name></action>
```

to

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/myjs.js#notify</name></action>
```

Because myjs.js is not found in your theme then it will try to look for it in the base theme folder

Answer (score 4):

It means that it cannot find the js in your theme nor the default folder.

Change to:

```
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/myjs.js#notify</name></action>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the file doesn't exist into your custom theme path then **skin_js** will return the base theme folder path. So make sure your file exist into your custom path and give the correct path.